# Checking JavaScript array equality using forEach

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check for array equality using `forEach` in JavaScript. This criteria is key, and the answer is not on Stack Overflow already.

The tests that are checking equality and expecting `true` are failing. I have a feeling I'm running into an issue to do with scope. Can someone please walk me through it?

```
function eql(arr1, arr2) {
  
  arr1.forEach((el) => {
    if (arr1[el] === arr2[el]) {
      return true;
    } 
  })
  return false
}
```

Here are the test results I want to change:

```
eql([], [])

Expected: true but got: false

eql(['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'])

Expected: true but got: false
```

Comment: please add some examples. and results. btw, `forEach` does not return a result from an inner return.

Comment: `return true` within the callback doesn't do anything. It is returning *from the callback` not from `eql`. You either need to convert to using a conventional loop, change it so the result is outside the callback and only changed within, or change to `.some()`/`.every()` and return the result of that.

Comment: `el` is not the index, it's each array item.

Comment: `return true` on the first match (if it would work, see comments above) doesn't tell you if all elements are equal.

Comment: you can use `every`, something like this: `arr1.every((e,i)=>e===arr2[i])`

Comment: @gorak `every` and most array methods skip holes. So, it will return true for `[,,3]` and `[1,2,3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be one of the many solutions

```js
function eql(arr1, arr2) {
  let returnStatement = true;

  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    returnStatement = false;
  } else if (returnStatement) {
    arr1.forEach((el, index) => {
      if (el !== arr2[index]) {
        returnStatement = false;
      }
    });
  }

  return returnStatement;
}

console.log(eql([1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4]))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things wrong with your code

- `forEach` doesnt return anything, it just iterates over the items performing some task
- even if `forEach` did return something you're not returning the result from your method!
- `el` is the element itself, not its index
- returning true from inside the method passed to `forEach` does not return from the `eql` method itself. Your method will *always* return false.
- ... but even if that worked,  returning `true` on the first match will not tell you the entire array equals

Your code can be shortened to

```js
function eql(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.length == arr2.length && arr1.every( (x,i) => x == arr2[i]);
}

console.log(eql([],[]));
console.log(eql([1,2,3],[1,2,3]));
console.log(eql([1,2,3],[1,2,2]));
console.log(eql([1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]));
```

Comment: `eql([,,3],[1,2,3])` returns `true` because `every` skips holes.

Comment: @adiga interesting, didnt know that. I suspect not so much of a problem in day to day use, but could be a gotcha somewhere down the road.

Comment: OP asks for a solution with `forEach` and then states that "this criteria is key". I agree with your solution, but it doesn't seem to fully fit the question…

Comment: @Barthy that line was added after this answer was posted. I'll leave it here for future visitors who might not have that requirement